# How can I avoid code duplication with Fragment callbacks to a details activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, code-duplication

I'm using a master/detail pattern with one activity managing the 2-pane view and the selector list and the other activity managing the detail fragments. I'm using an interface to handle fragment callbacks to the Activities.

There seems to be a lot of code duplication though with the details activity copying many of the callback methods from the 2-pane activity. Where appropriate, I've used static methods where context isn't required, but where context is required I'm not sure how to remove the code duplication neatly.

Inheritance with an Abstract parent Activity is an option but seems like a lot of overhead.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question here: [How many Activities vs Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363790/how-many-activities-vs-fragments)

I too was worried about the duplication of logic, and the answers I got caused quite a healthy debate.

---

In the end I chose to follow [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528434/383414), of putting as much of the logic into the `Fragments` themselves.

However other contributors seemed very keen on duplicating the logic as per the examples.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say u have Activity AB that controls Frag A and Fragment B.
MY ANSWER:
If the variable is used by Frag A and Frag B, put it in Activity AB. Then pass it to Frag A or Frag B everything they need it. Or have Frag A or Frag B retrieve it from Activity AB.
If the variable is used by Frag A only or Frag B only, put it in Frag A or Frag B respectively.

For methods that are used by both Frag A and Frag B, put those methods in another class and create instances of that class inside Frag A and Frag B for each of the 2 fragments to use.

The following is an answer I gave to another person. However, it seems relevant to your question so I am re-posting it here.
Inside Fragment A u need an interface that Activity AB can implement. 
In the sample android code, they have:

`private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;`

/*A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item selections.
*/

```
public interface Callbacks {
/*Callback for when an item has been selected. */    
      public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/*A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity. */    
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};
```

The Callback interface is put inside one of your Fragments (let’s say Fragment A). I think the purpose of this Callbacks interface is like a nested class inside Frag A which any Activity can implement. So if Fragment A was a TV, the CallBacks is the TV Remote (interface) that allows Fragment A to be used by Activity AB. I may be wrong about the details because I'm a noob but I did get my program to work perfectly on all screen sizes and this is what I used.

So inside Fragment A, we have:
(I took this from Android’s Sample programs)

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
// Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
// fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
//mCallbacks.onItemSelected( PUT YOUR SHIT HERE. int, String, etc.);
//mCallbacks.onItemSelected (Object);
}
```

And inside Activity AB we override the onItemSelected method:

```
public class AB extends FragmentActivity implements ItemListFragment.Callbacks {
//...
@Override
//public void onItemSelected (CATCH YOUR SHIT HERE) {
//public void onItemSelected (Object obj) {
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    //Pass Data to Fragment B. For example:
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(“FragmentB_package”, id);
    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

So inside Activity AB, you basically throwing everything into a Bundle and passing it to B. If u are not sure how to use a Bundle, look the class up.

I am basically going by the sample code that Android provided. The one with the DummyContent stuff. When u make a new Android Application Package, it's the one titled MasterDetailFlow.