# Android ActionBar pattern - multiple activities or fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, uinavigationbar

There are few similar questions on stackoverlow, but I haven't find clear explanation at any of the answers how to implement Action Bar pattern for more complex/multiple activities apps.

As I understand, there are two options to do this:

1.) implement multiple activities and in each of them implement/include action bar
--> problem with this is that when ever you lunch new activity, although it has the same looking action bar, it has that transition, and jumps through the screen, so it's obvious it's a new "window",new separate screen, and it kills that feeling of single app navigation frame.

2.) Use single FragmentActivity, with action bar within, and with multiple fragments that inflate content frame. 
--> this is pretty nice implementation of action bar pattern, but problem is that it goes against google's recommendation that one fragment should be in one activity in the case of phone. Or it doesn't?  From the "look and feel" I would say that Gmail app is done mostly this way.

3.) TabActivity - which is deprecated.

For the second solution (single activity, multiple fragments) I'm concerned if there would be any performance issue in the future? How does android handle memory in that case? will it kill inactive fragments to free space just like it does with the activities? Or it will kill the whole app, or user phone will be overloaded?

Maybe I'm missing something there, but I found implementing android navigation patterns and usage of fragments very confusing :/

Is there any reason against having one activity with multiple fragments on the phone? 
(there would be cca 5-6 fragments, with nested fragments in some of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you might think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363790/how-many-activities-vs-fragments) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12528434/1929093) to be useful.

Though you are talking about the actionbar, the real question is about the pattern of **ONE activity** with multiple fragments or **MULTIPLE activities**. As the former link states, though the "oversimplified tutorial" suggests of starting another activity to display item's content in Phone situation, this will probably cause some duplicated logic or codes.

Finally, using "FragmentActivity with multiple fragments" is recommended. As it is against the the google's recommendation, [Stephen Asherson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948905/stephen-asherson) says and I quote: " do not think of it as being forced to use many activities. Think of it as having the opportunity to split your code into many fragments, and saving memory when using them".

PS. just for your information, if you change the activity's actionbar in switching fragments, you might want to do something to correctly handle the UI change when "back" key is pressed and backstack is changed. Commonly, override the onbackstackchanged() function to handle the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I have seen and read posted link before I opened this question, but I haven't really understood it. 

Because, conclusion on that answer is that good practice is ActionBarSherlock pattern, that I'm unfamiliar with. I haven't use ABS, but I had download it's source when I was reading that posted link, but I wasn't been able to find mentioned demos. 

That's what I meant by - there are similar questions, but I haven't find a clear answer (at least not to me)

Comment: Back on topic, I found your answer useful...
just to be clear, are you stating that having one activity with multiple fragments is good in the terms of memory and performances? 
Android won't threat that as a nasty hack?

Comment: Glad this helps. Actually, ABS is just a non-official (but excellent) support library to offer actionbar support in lower versions of Android. As in Google's support library v4 the action bar is not supported for some unknown reasons. Yet it is a quite nice pattern, some genius develop the ActionBarSherlock to support API lower than 3.0 to use ActionBar. ABS helps a lot in those days without Android's official support for Actionbar. Later version of Google's support library(e.g. [android support v7](http://bit.ly/169kSWQ)) has already support ActionBar for API 7+.(1/2)

Comment: **MainPoint** for the verbose explaination is that the Design Pattern of using one activity with multiple fragments or multiple activity is **INDEPENDENT** of using ABS or not. The link's suggestion is still valid no matter you are using ABS or naive ActionBar or Support Library V7. **CALARIFY MY POINT** I think that using one activity with multiple fragments with different function is a better solution for 1)cleaner code 2)stronger scalabity. As the  performance issue, it is a complicated situation. But with multiple fragments, you can better control the current using resource and logic.(2/2)