# Best practices for Android action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm new to so and fairly new to android development too, and have already developed some bad habits.

Basically I've coded up an app, using an old learning source as a reference which did not cover fragments. As such I have several standard activities which I am in the process of converting to fragments.

One thing that I have not been able to find information on is the best practices for the action bar; is it best to define the action bar in the activity, or in the fragment?

I notice that calling onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) results in subtle changes from calling the same method in the activity, would it be possible to have advice on where it is best to call this and what benefits it provides?

Thanks

Comment: I personally prefer to handle the actionbar in the activity, if you feel the need to update the actionbar from a fragment, you can communicate with your activity through an interface. Other way around communicating from activity->fragment is harder.

Comment: You can also look at it this way. Activity is used to host fragments, as so Activity is used to host an actionbar. There isn't a direct relation between actionbar and a fragment.

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820173/android-actionbar-pattern-multiple-activities-or-fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, this method is a little bit different for fragment:

```
void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

and activity:

```
boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

The logic is quite simple: if you are going to have the same Action Bar (the same number of actions) across all the fragments, it's better to define it in the activity. If Action Bar layout depends on fragment, it's better to define it there.

Comment: You are still obliged to provide communication through the associating activity. Even if your actionbar depends on the content represented by the fragment