# Fragments VS Activities: Mixing both is a good idea?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-activity

Is it a good idea to mix `Fragments` and `Activities`? In my app, few windows need to be `Fragments` because they should have `ViewPager`. Other screens are normal.

So my question is, when you started using Fragments, do you use Fragments everywhere? Whether it is needed or not? My app should support 5 inch to 4 inch screen only anyway.

Comment: i use both in my application and work fine

Comment: i also use fragment activity

Comment: Check out some opinions on related thread: [How many Activities vs Fragments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363790/how-many-activities-vs-fragments)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: So basically what you mean is keep one activity? (The main)

Comment: You use activities anyway (at least one).
In some aspects, activities are easier to manage, but they have some limitations. It's OK to use both where it does the job.

Comment: No I'm just saying the opinions on that thread may be interesting for people reading this thread. Rather form your own opinion. e.g. Google & commonsware both seem to suggest building your phone app with many Activities, but building your tablet app with one Activity. My belief after all this time is that it is just a matter of style, no right or wrong way.