# Activities and fragments for Android Tablets and Handsets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I’m in the process of implementing a new version of an app and want it to move towards using fragments and thereby enabling it to be used on tablet devices.

I have read several approaches (e.g. [How many Activities vs Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363790/how-many-activities-vs-fragments)) and the guidelines on developer.android.com (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html).

The Android Guide aims for one monolithic Activity for Tablets that deals with replacing fragments as needed whereas the handheld version does it by using multiple activities.

See example: http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png

**Why are these two approaches not combined?**

Let’s say FragmentA from the above image is the menu of my application where I can select a different aspect and FragmentB is the corresponding Content for the selected item.

*Tablet devices*

If my application can be separated into different aspects that correspond to the items in the menu, wouldn’t it make more sense to encapsulate the functionality behind each menu item inside a different Activity instead of using one monolithic one?

Selecting an item in the menu would exchange Activity A by ActivityB/C/D/E. Whereas those are configured in the same way, in the sense that is has a menuFragment on the left and its content fragment on the right. Interactions in the contentFragment would replace it with different fragments and so on. But the functionality would be covered by the specific Activity that holds it. So I would not have one monolithic Activity, but smaller and more specific ones.

*Handheld devices*

Similar to the above, instead of using a different activity per ”screen” I could reuse ActivityA/B/C/D/E and their contentFragment in a singlePane-Layout by replacing it accordingly by specifying the singlePane-layout for handheld devices. One Activity manages one task with several fragments.

So I would end up with the same number of Activities for tablets and handheld devices that are configured the way to handle both cases a bit different. Activities would be neither gigantic and full of logic nor totally dumbed down, but somewhere in between.

**Is there something wrong with this approach?**

I’m currently thinking about how to move forward and this approach seems reasonable to me, but maybe there are things I have not considered that make it not the best choice.

Comment: I think the idea is that most of your control logic is in the fragments themselves. Your activity subclasses barely do anything besides swapping fragments around. I am curious to see what others have to say. The current system seems a tad convoluted, but that's probably because fragments were only conceived for Android 3.0 and backward compatibility had to be maintained. In iOS, both Activities and Fragments are analogous to UIViewControllers, which can be nested however you like so the implementation is more flexible and easily adapted how you like.

Comment: Coming from this side, conceptually, it appears to me that a UITabBarController or UINavigationController is similar to an Activity and the viewControllers it displays are like Fragments, right?

Comment: UITabBarController and UINavigationController are both subclasses of UIViewController, in the same way FragmentActivity is a subclass of Activity. In both cases, you can use the superclass to control all your views directly. But in Android, Fragments can also be used to control views. In iOS, you can just nest the UIViewControllers however you like, but in Android you can only put a Fragment in a FragmentActivity, or use an Activity directly.