# Is gmail App using more fragments then activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, gmail, fragment

I am working over the application as same concept as gmail, i know about **fragment** and **activity**. But need to be more specific and want to know about the **Top** **applications** using what??

Comment: The question you asking is comparatively broad...because usage of no of fragment or activity depends on requirement...Also understand Fragment vs Activity usage..I prefer more Fragment compare to Activity due to it's modularity. Yes sometimes handling multiple Fragments becomes overhead... and also in terms of other factors handling multiple Activity also becomes overhead

Answer (score 1):

Of course YES, Without fragments maintenance and development of app would be really hard.

For more information you can read it: [So what are the exact advantages of Fragments in Android 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695408/so-what-are-the-exact-advantages-of-fragments-in-android-3-0?answertab=active#tab-top)

Or Google it: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&espv=2&q=android+advantage+fragment&oq=android+advantage+fragment&gs_l=serp.12..0i8i7i30.147164.148475.0.150178.3.3.0.0.0.0.215.409.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.2.408.68o3C-Tt_g0